# VueJS: How to get nested object value from vuex store?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex

I am trying to access nested property of store state data but it is undefined when I try to access. I have following data

```js
const state = {
  entity: {
    initial: {valid: false},
    general: {valid: false},
    buildFiles: {valid: false},
    license: {valid: false},
    author: {valid: false},
  }
};
const getters = {
  ENTITY: (state: any): Submission => {
    return state.entity; // Works fine
  },
  INITIAL: (state) => {
    console.log(state.entity); // Prints observable with entity and properties
    console.log(state.entity.initial); // Prints undefined
    return state.entity.initial;
  },
  
};
```

All I am trying to do is use getters from the component. Is there any way I can access property intitial?

Comment: I don't see any problem in the vuex store so far. Can you please share how you access your getters in the component?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't overwrite the whole `entity` before checking getters?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need return state as a function. And your getters needed some a little changes: Try some thing like this:

```
const state = () => ({
  entity: {
    initial: { valid: false },
    general: { valid: false },
    buildFiles: { valid: false },
    license: { valid: false },
    author: { valid: false },
  },
})
const getters = {
  ENTITY: (state) => (submission) => {
    return state.entity // Works fine
  },
  INITIAL: (state) => {
    console.log(state.entity) // Prints observable with entity and properties
    console.log(state.entity.initial) // Prints undefined
    return state.entity.initial
  },
}
```